# Process started from C# that invokes a PowerShell script is not able to run Postgres database queries

Tags: c#, database, wpf, postgresql, powershell

I have a WPF application that starts `powershell.exe` as process (code in C#) with my script as argument. My PowerShell script restarts a Windows service and updates the result into a Postgres database.

The problem I am having is that the PowerShell script when invoked from C# is not able to update the database, but everything works fine when run from PowerShell console itself. I am not getting any errors with the database update part, but nothing reflects into the DB. (according to the script the query was run but the results are not reflected).

I'm running the C# code in a x64 environment only. I am not able to capture where the problem is actually.

Also, everything works as expected when I restart the server, but only once. 
All other parts work the same after that except the database update part and getting no error also.

Tried running the WPF project in x64 bit mode. 
Query is correct.

PowerShell Code that connects to the Postgres database:

```bsh
$DBConnectionString = "Driver={PostgreSQL UNICODE(x64)};Server=$MyServer;Port=$MyPort;Database=$MyDB;Uid=$MyUid;Pwd=$MyPass;"
Write-Log $DBConnectionString
$DBConn = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
$DBConn.ConnectionString = $DBConnectionString;
$DBConn.Open();
$DBCmd = $DBConn.CreateCommand();
$DBCmd.CommandText = 'UPDATE public."' + 'AllLogs" SET "Status" = ' + $Status +
                     ', "ReturnMessage" = ' + "'" + $ReturnMessage + "'" +
                     ' WHERE "AllLogs"."LogID" = ' + "'" + $LogID + "' ;"
Write-Log $DBCmd.CommandText

$rdr = $DBCmd.ExecuteReader()
$tbl = New-Object Data.DataTable
$tbl.Load($rdr)
$rdr.Close()
$a = $tbl | Format-Table -AutoSize
$DBConn.Close();
```

C# code that starts the process:

```cs
var pi = new ProcessStartInfo();
pi.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe";
pi.Arguments = arglist;
pi.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
pi.UseShellExecute = true;
pi.Verb = "runas";
var pr = Process.Start(pi);
```

The PowerShell process should be able to update the database. and then it will be reflected on the application UI.

Everything works fine when I start the same process from PowerShell console - it updates the database and the same reflects on the application UI also. But not when the process starts from C#.

Comment: Please update the question to show how the `.Arguments` property is populated. Also consider in-process use of the PowerShell SDK instead, which allows you to examine the output streams individually.

Comment: -command & 'C:\AW\NewTest.ps1' -Inp '1' -LogID e1bbfd4f-eb1b-4b16-bf4a-1f0c1b8909a4 ..... This is the value that is populated into the .Arguments property

Comment: Please always add clarifications _directly to the question_ - don't post them in comments. The more interesting question is how you determined that you're not getting any errors, given that your C# code shows no attempt to capture and examine output. Generally, please strive for an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or as close as you can get to one.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The issue is resolved now - i just had to add some wait time for the db query to be executed as the subprocess was getting terminated as soon as the main process gets completed. Also i have just shared a part of code that does the deed. No point sharing error handling and logging - from which i was pretty sure there was no error. Anyways thanks for the response.